# CSS Footer slight space after

Tags: css, footer

I am having an issue in removing the white space after footer. I was able to remove it in chrome setting a - margin-bottom but that doesn't work well with Firefox or IE. I'm not quite sure I understand why the white space is even there.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="footer">
  <section class="footer-inner">
    <p class="footer-text">Copyright</p>
  </section>
</div>

.footer {
  height: 300px;
}
.footer-inner {
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: #E0E6E6;
}
.footer-text {
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trws2062/ or http://www.johndayers.com/versions/v9/footer_branch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your footer is currently a p class, which is creating a bottom margin on the footer:

```
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

Change the footer from being a paragraph to a div, like so:

```
<div class="footer-text">
    Copyright &copy; 2015 etc...
</div>
```

Comment: wow. Thanks bootstrap. This did fix it and is the culpruit so this is how i should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Because bootstrap will add margin in p element,
set margin-bottom in .footer-text should work

```
.footer-text {
  padding: 100px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```